# How does the logic "column < row + 1" work? The output gives half an asterisk pyramid

Tags: c#

This code creates half a pyramid on the compiler, but I'm not sure how that works. The only thing I understand is that the `column < row + 1` line is what influences the code, because when I change it to `column < 10`, then it creates a square when run.

```
for(int row = 0; row < 10; row++) {
    for(int column = 0; column < row + 1; column++) {   
        Console.Write("*");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
} 

//The output gives half the asterisk pyramid.
//I don't get the logic of how "row + 1" works.
//How does this influence the asterisk to not be entered in the particular places?
```

Comment: Welcome to GDSE. While some general programming questions are [on-topic](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here, most belong on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) instead.

Comment: ... But this one does not. Better take some paper and a pen and trace out what the algorithm does for some small value (e.g. 3 instead of 10).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Quentin says, this is pretty clear to see for yourself if you walk through what the program is doing step by step, following [the rules of a `for` loop](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/for).

Let's draw row 0

column = 0, that's less than 0+1, so we draw an *
Now column = 1, that's not less than 0+1, so we exit the inner loop
We drop down a line.

The outer loop repeats: now we're drawing row 1

column = 0, that's less than 1+1, so we draw an *
Now column = 1, that's less than 1+1, so we draw an *
Now column = 2, that's not less than 1+1, so we exit the inner loop
We drop down a line.

The outer loop repeats: now we're drawing row 2

column = 0, that's less than 2+1, so we draw an *
Now column = 1, that's less than 2+1, so we draw an *
Now column = 2, that's less than 2+1, so we draw an *
Now column = 3, that's not less than 2+1, so we exit the inner loop
We drop down a line.

What do we have so far?

```
*
**
***
```